# When to replace localhost with service name in docker?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, express, mern

I have reactjs app and express app dockerized. 
This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  client:
    image: react-app
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    container_name: mern-app-client
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
  server:
    image: express-app
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    container_name: mern-app-server
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
```

I have 2 dockerfiles, 1 in each client and server (built from node images). 
After running docker compose up, I have server running at http://localhost:5000 and react app at http://localhost:3000. 
Everything is working fine when I have base_url as http://localhost:5000 in react app's axios/fetch. In some blogs, not necessarily of mern, I saw localhost being replaced with service name. 
I tried the same and replaced the base_url in react app with http://server:5000 but it didn't work. 
Now I am confused in the core concept of when should we replace the base_url and why is it needed?
I would be very grateful if somebody could explain.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to your browser and type `http://localhost:3000` in, the browser makes a call to the `client` container, does an HTTP GET to retrieve the Javascript code, and the *browser* actually runs the code.  This is a critical difference: any `fetch` calls or similar from your React application are running in the end user's browser, not inside Docker.

If a call is coming from the browser; it is part of your front-end application; or it is otherwise coming from outside Docker, then you need to use the host system's DNS name and the first published `ports:` number.  If the browser and the containers are both running on the same system you can use `localhost`; if Docker is running in a VM (perhaps on the older Docker Toolbox setup) you need the VM's IP address.

```
+-------------+                         +-----------------------+
| Browser     |  http://localhost:3000/ | client:               |
|   React app | ----------------------> |   ports: ['3000:...'] |
+-------------+                         +-----------------------+
```

It's also possible for one container to directly call each other.  Maybe the `client` container makes a call to `server` as part of prerendering a page before it gets sent back to the browser; maybe `server` has a backing `db`.  In this case you can use the Compose service name as a host name, and whatever port the server process is listening on.  `ports:` aren't required and are ignored if present.

```
+----------+                      +-------------------------+
| server:  |  postgres://db:5432/ | db:                     |
|          | -------------------> |   # ports: ['...:5432'] |
+----------+                      +-------------------------+
```

This setup is described further in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  You do not generally need to explicitly specify `container_name:` or `networks:`; Compose provides reasonable working defaults for these things for you.

For a browser-based application that needs to be configured with URLs for both the application itself and also a separate API server, a good practice is to set up a reverse proxy as a container.  This could be something like Nginx, or in a pure development environment Webpack's proxy server.  Since the proxy makes calls between two containers, you'd configure it with the Docker-internal URL `http://server:5000` for the backend.  This means that both the in-browser code and the backend APIs are on the same host and port, though, and so you can use a path-only relative URL `/api/...`, bypassing the question of which host and port to use.

Comment: So now we can't replace localhost with service name as the browser is outside docker and it has no idea about the service names? But can we replace it with IP address or domain name once deployed?

Comment: What will be the axios base URL in react app if we are using nginx reverse proxy?