# React is not hitting django apis on kubernetes cluster

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and this is my first time deploying a react-django web app to Kubernetes cluster.

I have created:

1. frontend.yaml # to run npm server
2. backend.yaml # to run django server
3. backend-service.yaml # to make django server accessible for react.

In my frontend.yaml file I am passing `REACT_APP_HOST` and `REACT_APP_PORT` as a env variable and changed URLs in my react app to:

```
axios.get('http://'+`${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}`+':'+`${process.env.REACT_APP_PORT}`+'/todolist/api/bucket/').then(res => {
      setBuckets(res.data);
      setReload(false);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
```

and my URL becomes `http://backend-service:8000/todolist/api/bucket/`

here `backend-service` is name of backend-service that I am passing using env variable `REACT_APP_HOST`.

I am not getting any errors, but when I used `kubectl port-forward <frontend-pod-name> 3000:3000` and accessed `localhost:3000` I saw my react app page but it did not hit any django apis.

On chrome, I am getting error:

```
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

and in Mozilla:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://backend-service:8000/todolist/api/bucket/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Please help on this issue, I have spent 3 days but not getting any ideas.

**frontend.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: frontend
  name: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 1234567890/todolist:frontend-v13
        name: react-todolist
        env:
          - name: REACT_APP_HOST
            value: "backend-service"
          - name: REACT_APP_PORT
            value: "8000"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/log/
            name: frontend
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args:
          - npm start;
      volumes:
        - name: frontend
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/
```

**backend.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: backend
  name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: backend-sva
      containers:
      - image: 1234567890/todolist:backend-v11
        name: todolist
        env:
          - name: DB_NAME
            value: "todolist"
          - name: MYSQL_HOST
            value: "mysql-service"
          - name: MYSQL_USER
            value: "root"
          - name: MYSQL_PORT
            value: "3306"
          - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            value: "mysql123"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/log/
            name: backend
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args:
          - apt-get update;
            apt-get -y install vim;
            python manage.py makemigrations bucket;
            python manage.py migrate;
            python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      volumes:
        - name: backend
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/
```

**backend-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: backend
  name: backend-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: backend
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**frontend docker file**

```
FROM node:14.16.1-alpine

COPY package.json /app/react-todolist/react-todolist/
WORKDIR /app/react-todolist/react-todolist/

RUN npm install

COPY . /app/react-todolist/react-todolist/

EXPOSE 3000
```

**backend docker file**

```
FROM python:3.6

COPY requirements.txt ./app/todolist/
WORKDIR /app/todolist/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/todolist/
```

**django settings**

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Rest Frame Work
    'rest_framework',
    # CORS
    'corsheaders',

    # Apps
    'bucket',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

kind: Ingress

metadata:
  name: todolist-ingress

spec:
  rules:
    - host: kubernetes.docker.internal
      http:
       paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: frontend-service
            servicePort: 3000
        
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: backend-service
            servicePort: 8000
```

**react axios api**

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://'+`${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}`+':'+`${process.env.REACT_APP_PORT}`+'/todolist/api/bucket/', {
      headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
    }).then(res => {
      setBuckets(res.data);
      setReload(false);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }, [reload])
```

**web app github link** https://github.com/vgautam99/ToDoList

Comment: The `axios.get()` call is being invoked from your browser; it can't see the Kubernetes-internal Service DNS names.  You might set up an Ingress object to route requests to pods, and use path-only relative URLs in your front-end code.

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67452040/10008173) to [When to replace localhost with service name in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67451389/when-to-replace-localhost-with-service-name-in-docker/) might help you understand what runs where, though there are some details around Docker/Compose that are a little different in Kubernetes.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, I have added `ingress.yaml` file and also `axios API` that I am using, I am able to access web app UI using `http://kubernetes.docker.internal/` but still I am getting same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the community!

I reproduced your example and made it work fine.
I forked your repository, made some changes to js files and package.json and added Dockerfiles (you can see this commit [here](https://github.com/fivecatscats/ToDoList/commit/74790836659232284832688beb2e1779660d7615)

Since I didn't change database settings in `settings.py` I attached it as a `configMap` to backend deployment (see [here](https://github.com/fivecatscats/ToDoList/blob/master/backend-deploy.yaml#L37-L39) how it's done). Config map was created by this command:

`kubectl create cm django1 --from-file=settings.py`

The trickiest part here is to use your domain name `kubernetes.docker.internal` and add your port with `/backend` path to environment variables you're passing to your frontend application (see [here](https://github.com/fivecatscats/ToDoList/blob/master/frontend-deploy.yaml#L21-L24))

Once this is done, it's time to set up an ingress controller (this one uses apiVersion - `extestions/v1beta1` as it's done in your example, however it'll be deprecated soon, so it's advised to use `networking.k8s.io/v1` - example  of a newer apiVersion is [here](https://github.com/fivecatscats/ToDoList/blob/master/ingress-after-1-22.yaml)):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: todolist-backend-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: kubernetes.docker.internal
      http:
       paths:
        - path: /backend(/|$)(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: backend-service
            servicePort: 8000
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: todolist-frontend-ingress
  annotations:
spec:
  rules:
    - host: kubernetes.docker.internal
      http:
       paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: frontend-service
            servicePort: 3000
```

I set it up in two different ingresses because there are some issues with `rewrite-target` and `regex` using root path `/`. As you can see we use `rewrite-target` here because requests are supposed to hit `/todolist/api/bucket` path instead of `/backend/todolist/api/bucket` path.
Please see [nginx rewrite annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)

Next step is to find an IP address to test your application from the node where kubernetes is running and from the web.
To find IP addresses and ports run `kubectl get svc` and `find ingress-nginx-controller`:

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
backend-service                      ClusterIP      10.100.242.79    <none>          8000/TCP                     21h
frontend-service                     ClusterIP      10.110.102.96    <none>          3000/TCP                     21h
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.107.31.20     192.168.1.240   80:31323/TCP,443:32541/TCP   8d
```

There are two options: `CLUSTER-IP` and `EXTERNAL-IP` if you have loadbalancer set up.
On your kubernetes  control plane, you can run a simple checking test with `curl` command using `CLUSTER-IP` address. In my case it looks like:

`curl http://kubernetes.docker.internal/ --resolve kubernetes.docker.internal:80:10.107.31.20`

And next test is:

`curl -I http://kubernetes.docker.internal/backend/todolist/api/bucket --resolve kubernetes.docker.internal:80:10.107.31.20`

Output will be like:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 14 May 2021 12:21:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: /todolist/api/bucket/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Vary: Origin
```

Next step is access your application via web browser. You'll need to correct `/etc/hosts` on your local machine (linux/Mac OS, for Windows it's a bit different, but very easy to find) to match `kubernetes.docker.internal` domain with proper IP address.

If you're using a `load balancer` then `EXTERNAL-IP` is the right address.
If you don't have a `load balancer` then it's possible to reach out to the node directly. You can find IP address in cloud console and add it to `/etc/hosts`. In this case you will need to use a different port. In my case it was `31323` (you can find it above in `kubectl get svc` output).

When it's set up, I hit the application in my web-browser by `http://kubernetes.docker.internal:31323`

(Repository is [here](https://github.com/fivecatscats/ToDoList) feel free to use everything you need from it)